# How to change the background image of my main activity in Android to a random jpeg on clicking a button?

Tags: android

My code currently changes colours randomly when I press a button. It picks up a colour randomly from an array of colours. I want to create an array of images and set the background to an image randomly.

facts.java:

```
public class facts {

String f[]={"this is number one","This is number two","This is number three","Last one"};
String c[]={"#C6FF00","#1DE9B6","#3949AB","#C2185B","#F44336","#FF1744","#880E4F","#311B92","#651FFF","#2196F3","#006064","#43A047","#00C853","#CDDC39","#33691E","#C6FF00","#FFA000","#BF360C","#FF5722","#FF6D00","#455A64","#212121"};
int k=0;



public String nextfact()
{
    k=new Random().nextInt(f.length);
    String randomStr = f[k];
    return randomStr;
}

public String nextcolor()
{
    String randomc= c[new Random().nextInt(c.length)];
    return randomc;
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
facts fac=new facts();
TextView factBox;
RelativeLayout abc;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    factBox=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.factTextbox);
    abc=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.lala);
}
public void genfact(View view)
{
    int index=0;
    factBox.setText(fac.nextfact());
    abc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(fac.nextcolor()));

}
}
```

Comment: do you mean an array of drawables (things like png files) or an array of ImageViews? and please post the xml layout file(s)

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of images, and then use random number to get one of them:

```
 int[] backgrounds= new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2...};

 Random random = new Random();

 Integer rand = random.nextInt(backgrounds.length());

 abc.setBackground(backgrounds[rand]);
```